# Can source control software be used for your technical documents?

Tags: version-control

I know you can use source control software for source code, but can you use it for your technical documents as well?  For example, can you store a Word document and it keep a history of changes (I know it has track changes, it's just and example)? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because it's only an assertion: yes. But beware that Word documents are binary blobs for most intents, so you'd have to reconstruct the entire old version to compare differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a Windows platform, then [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) has some really useful features that will let you diff (but unfortunately not merge) Word documents. It interacts with an installed Word directly, and when you request a diff it runs a script that loads both documents to compare into Word and uses Word's built-in document compare to compare them.

With that feature, combined with Subversion's locking (where editors must request a lock on a document to turn off the read-only flag), I have found it very easy to manage Word documents with Subversion. It's not quite as convenient as plain text, but when you must produce Word documents it's certainly doable.

Having said the above, in general terms documents are a product of the software development process and *must* be version controlled in some way. Otherwise, your process is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Version control systems, while they can store arbitrary files like Word documents, are much more effective on text documents edited as source by the user, because the differences can be represented in a line-oriented fashion meaningfully to the user.

For this and [many other reasons](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s01.html), I write all my documentation these days in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) source files, edited along with other source files and tracked in version control. The HTML and PDF versions are rendered along with the rest of the project's generated files at build time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

However, note that many documents will be stored as binaries.  This will limit the utility of storing them in source control, making it harder to see fine-grained changes.

If you have LaTeX documents or XML-based documents then things work even better.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can source control anything, I've heard about designers source controlling their Photoshop files. If you always write clear commit messages, it's easy to roll back to a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word documents are pretty much treated as binary files, and so it's pretty much impossible to diff or merge different versions of a Word file.

That doesn't mean it can't, or shouldn't, be put under version control, just that it won't help you much in resolving conflicts.

If you want that, you may want to store your documents in a plaintext format (such as .tex)

Comment: Well, most source control systems allow you to specify a special diff program for a filetype, so you could use your wordprocessor as the diff tool (most allow that, at least OO.org and MS Word). Merging might be harder though, so you should probably set them as "not mergeable".

Comment: @sleske, choosing a diff tool will only affect how the tool *present* differences to the user. It won't help the VCS tool to figure out what's changed (unless it has specific merging support for your specific binary file type) when merging; all conflicts will just be thrown in the face of the user.

Comment: @bignose
Yes, just what I wrote :-). "you should probably set them as 'not mergeable' ". Some VCS (e.g. Subversion) let you specify custom merge programs. If you really need it, you could write a custom merge program for MS Word etc., then you could actually merge these files. Hence the "probably" above ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Using source control for technical documents is a great idea, but as many others have said, Word is not the best file format for this.

A Word file is actually a folder of XML files under the covers (rename a .docx file to filename.zip and unzip it to see the folder). In theory you could create a zip folder for every version, store the folder in Git source control, and see the version differences. However, this is really impractical and of limited value.

You could also use Pandoc to convert each .docx file version to Markdown and put the Markdown files under source control.

Word also has a built-in file-compare feature (Review > Compare). This will markup the differences between any two .docx files.

I like to use Markdown or AsciiDoc text files for writing technical documents along with Git for version control. Git is reasonably easy to learn to use for the basic needs. This system gives me perfect control of the document and an understanding of the history of the document as it changes over time with each draft, reviewers' comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. We do this at work and really helps keep track of the tech docs, which sometimes can change as frequently as the source code itself :)

Comment: what format do you use for the tech files?  word, notepad, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You can upload files to your version control and keep an history of change for them.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else said, you can definitely use source control for your technical documentation. But, I'm definitely going to come down on the side of the poster who suggested restructured test. The whole point of revision control is to be able to see diffs and merge amongst them, and in my book, you're going to need to be using text files to do it.

Some other options aside from restuctureText are [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) and [DITA](http://dita.xml.org/). They're pretty popular in the technical publishing world and both are based on XML, so there are some decent support tools for them. For DocBook, you might check out [XML Mind](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the MS collaboration solution - namely, [Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx) - uses SharePoint to achieve just this. I know almost nothing of SharePoint, and have been easily using it to keep versions of technical word docs for a while now.

If you want to use it directly from within word, you can try the word add-in available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163498.aspx).

Assuming you use Visual Studio as the primary interface for team system services, click View->Team Explorer. If you haven't already, set up your repository server and add your project (there are nice online [video tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb507749.aspx) for most of this stuff).

Under your project tree node, go to *Documents*, and create/add your doc. Edit it, check in & check out at will (and let your teammates do the same). When you need a version history of the doc, open it *from the team explorer window*. In the word app that would launch, you should have (by default) at the right a 'SharePoint' panel.  (I'm writing this without access to a team client, but I'm pretty sure I'm not making any un-recoverable mistakes..). In it, navigate to the *info* tab, and scroll down to *'History...'* (or is it *Versions...*?  exact details tomorrow.)

Answer (score 0):

I keep my résumé as a LibreOffice document in a Git repo. It works fine; the idea that version control doesn’t work with binary files is absolutely false.

What is true is that binary files need appropriate diff and merge tools, but Git lets you specify those. I’ve never bothered to do so in my case, but diff utilities for LibreOffice/OpenOffice files do exist.